# Как постоянно менять значение переменной в функции при нажатии кнопки? python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

переменная fond прибавляет к себе единицу в функции Ircutsk.

```
fond = 0
 
def Ircutsk(fond):
    fond += 1
    print(fond)

sled = Button(text='Следующий день', command=lambda : Ircutsk(fond))
sled.place(y=335, x=140)
```

Эта функция включается при нажатии на кнопку. Но в консоли при нажатии каждый раз выводится **`1`** хотя по идее должно быть `0 + 1 =1` значит после второго нажатия `1 + 1 = 2` и т.д. но так не происходит.

Comment: Переменную внутри функции надо сделать global fond

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте переменную глобальной:

```
fond = 0
 
def Ircutsk():
    global fond #Обьявляем переменную глобальной

    fond += 1
    print(fond)

sled = Button(text='Следующий день', command=Ircutsk)
sled.place(y=335, x=140)
```

Comment: Спасибо только тогда уж надо убрать сам параметр fond из функции и при вызове самой функции